# Was Daniel a part of Israelite Royalty?

Tags: hebrew, daniel, bible

In the opening of the book of Daniel it alludes to that fact that the Hebrew boys were part of Royalty and nobility can anyone else confirm this?

> Dan 1:3, 4 - Then the king ordered Ashpenaz, the chief of his court
> officials, to bring in some Israelites from the **royal family**
> [literally: from the seed of the kingdom] and **the nobility**— young men
> without blemish, handsome, gifted in all wisdom, knowledgeable, quick
> to understand, and qualified to serve in the king’s palace—and to
> teach them the language and literature of the Chaldeans.

Comment: Hi Edson, you will need to provide a specific verse in the question

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  Valid questions here must have a specific passage to examine.  I will add this for you.

Comment: Is there something that make you doubt this explicit statement?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the significance of Daniel's statements regarding the captivity, Isaiah's prophecy to Hezekiah must be understood.  Daniel is confirming that prophecy.

First, Daniel's statement:

> <sup>3</sup> And the king spake unto Ashpenaz the master of his
> eunuchs, that he should bring certain of the children of Israel, and
> **of the king's seed, and of the princes;** <sup>4</sup> Children in whom
> was no blemish, but well favoured, and skilful in all wisdom, and
> cunning in knowledge, and understanding science, and **such as had
> ability in them to stand in the king's palace,** and whom they might
> teach the learning and the tongue of the Chaldeans. (Daniel 1:3-4,
> KJV)

While Nebuchadnezzar was a wise king who respected ability and did not elevate only royalty in his courts, those of royal lineage would be in the most favorable position to fulfill the king's requirements.  And his capture of the "king's seed, and of the princes" had been prophesied long beforetime.

Isaiah's prophecy:

> <sup>16</sup> And Isaiah said unto Hezekiah, Hear the word of the
> LORD. <sup>17</sup> Behold, the days come, that all that is in thine
> house, and that which thy fathers have laid up in store unto this day,
> shall be carried into Babylon: nothing shall be left, saith the LORD.
> <sup>18</sup> **And of thy sons that shall issue from thee, which thou
> shalt beget, shall they take away; and they shall be eunuchs in the
> palace of the king of Babylon.** (2 Kings 20:16-18, KJV)

Daniel would certainly have been familiar with this prophecy.  It is even likely that his deportment in Babylon were tempered by this prophecy.  Knowing it had been predicted, and was a part of God's master plan, Daniel would have found it easier to accept the situation.  Most importantly, Daniel writes in confirmation of the fulfillment of the prophecy, to strengthen the faith of those who should afterward read and understand it.

Daniel also references multiple times, as first indicated in the quote of Daniel 1:3 above, that he was among the "eunuchs."  This, too, had been prophesied.

A final, minor clue, lies in the fact that "Daniel" was one of David's own sons, and the name may have been considered worthy of royalty in the generations following.

> Now these were the sons of David, which were born unto him in Hebron;
> the firstborn Amnon, of Ahinoam the Jezreelitess; the second Daniel,
> of Abigail the Carmelitess: (1 Chronicles 3:1, KJV)

### Conclusion

While we do not have full confirmation (proof) of Daniel's lineage, we have sufficient evidence to assert with confidence that Daniel was indeed of the royal line of Judah, even as [rabbinic tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_in_rabbinic_literature) claims.  His own testimony confirming the fulfillment of Isaiah's prophecy gives great weight to this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The key to finding out if Daniel was part of royalty can be found in verse 6:

> Among those who were chosen were some **from Judah**: Daniel, Hananiah, Mishael and Azariah. (ESV) [bold mine]

Daniel, and his companions, were from the tribe of Judah which was also the tribe from which King David was born. As promised by Jehovah God himself, the line of kings for Israel would come from David's lineage. ([2 Samuel 7:11-16](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001054/91/0))

The original Hebrew wording is "and some of the descendants of the king":

[image: Screenshot of the interlinear for Daniel 1:3 from Biblehub]

So, yes, Daniel was of the royal line because he was of the tribe of Judah but possibly due to lost records (see [Ezra 2:62](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/15/2#study=discover&v=15:2:62)) it could not be verified if he was actual nobility.

[Unless otherwise noted, all scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]